# how to scroll div content inside fixed wrapper

Tags: css, html, fixed, floating

I have my fixed wrapper div inside which i want to add a floating div blog with content.
and i want to scroll content of floating blog div with vertical scroll while fixed wrapper remains as it is.
for example i want like this http://labs.burntfeathers.com/?theme=village

Comment: Can you give extra some hits.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you want, but does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sBQ3m/) work?

Comment: Overflow-y:scroll adds scroller to inner div. But i want to scroll it using original browser scroller.                                        For help go to The blog of this link http://labs.burntfeathers.com/?theme=village